# How to use a negative np.array for a scatterplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am new to python but I am struggling to use the following np array (each array would have 10 negative values like this one)

['-402.733' '-409.492' '-365.059' '-444.696' '-393.2' '-428.249'
'-449.477' '-458.534']

as an input into a scatter;
I can't tell if I should use regex to ensure the hyphen is ascii and numerical or if I should just convert the np.arrrays to lists. Both of these I've tried and encountered different errors, I just think my format may be bad?

Also apologies for the format of this question if its no to standard. Please keep in mind since I am new that I do struggle reading/understanding most stack overflow responses.

```
ax.scatter([0, 1.178, 2.105], [(np_d_C0, np_d_C1. astype(float), np_d_C2. astype(float))], color="m", marker='*', label="S1")
ax.scatter([0, 0.721, 1.238], [(np_b_C0. astype(float), np_b_C1. astype(float), np_b_C2. astype(float))], color="b", marker='*', label="NC")
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05, 0.1, 0.1),
          ncol=3, fancybox=True, shadow=True)

z = np.polyfit([0, 1.178, 2.105], (np_d_C0. astype(float), np_d_C1. astype(float), np_d_C2. astype(float)), 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot([0, 1.178, 2.105], p([0, 1.178, 2.105]), "r--", color="m")

z2 = np.polyfit([0, 0.721, 1.238], (np_b_C0. astype(float), np_b_C1. astype(float), np_b_C2. astype(float)), 1)
p2 = np.poly1d(z2)
plt.plot([0, 0.721, 1.238], p2([0, 0.721, 1.238]), "r--", color="b")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the shown code? What's the error?

Comment: It would probably make sense to have all arrays immediately in type float instead of converting them constantly.  As always, it would help a lot if you showed the complete error trace (as text). Could you include the approaches you tried and their problems?  Most editors nowadays have syntax highlighting. So, pasting the numbers (without the quotes) should immediately indicate whether the minus sign is really a minus sign.

Comment: Can you include how you read the numbers from file? In which format are they stored?

Comment: When using this format .np_d_C0.astype(np.float32), I get this error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Originally, when I was using the mean of the groups I didn't receive any errors but now I want to show all the raw data points but because they're negative I am struggling. I think.

Comment: The raw data comes from a csv but I'm not sure how to tell if that csv hyphen is a true negative or not? I make the code loop through csv's and compile concentrations to certain groups so I can graph them. They are start as a list and get converted to a np.array

Comment: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  _data = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy,
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):